# How can I add a row above the second row in a table? Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

By default, rows gets added below. There's a lot of answers on SO for adding rows above, but not using `ListObjects`. I appreciate the help.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim the_sheet As Worksheet
Dim table_list_object As ListObject
Dim table_object_row As ListRow

Set the_sheet = Sheets("Decision Log")
Set table_list_object = the_sheet.ListObjects(1)
Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to change the position of listrow to 2 : `Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add(2)`

Comment: @Fadi That does the same thing except inserts a row after the 2nd row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows(1).Range.EntireRow.Insert
```

Comment: Thanks, Brian. Unfortunately, this code triggers no change at all. A row is no longer inserted.

Comment: @GovindRai Hmmm. I tested it and it worked perfectly for me. Not sure.

Comment: @GovindRai You may need to set `table_object_row` after inserting.